# Linux kernel: Find all drivers reachable via syscalls

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, system-calls, android-kernel

I am comparing a mainline Linux kernel source with a modified copy of the same source that has many drivers added. A little background: That modified source is an Android kernel source, it contains many drivers added by the vendor, SoC manufacturer, Google etc.

I am trying to identify all drivers added in the modified source that are reachable from userspace via any syscalls. I'm looking for some systematic or ideally automatic way to find all these to avoid the manual work.

For example, char device drivers are of interest, since I could perform some `openat`, `read`, `write`, `ioctl` and `close` syscalls on them if there is a corresponding device file. To find new character device drivers, I could first find all new files in the source tree and then grep them for `struct file_operations`. But besides char drivers, what else is there that I need to look for?

I know that the syscalls mentioned above do some kind of "forwarding" to the respective device driver associated with the file. But are there other syscalls that do this kind of forwarding? I think I would have to focus on all these syscalls, right?

Is there something I can grep for in source files that indicates that syscalls can lead there? How should I go about this to find all these drivers?

---

Update (narrowing down):

- I am targeting specific devices (e.g. Huawei P20 Lite), so I know relevant architecture and hardware. But for the sake of this question, we can just assume that hardware for whatever driver is present. It doesn't really matter in my case if I invoked a driver and it reported back that no corresponding hardware is present, as long as I can invoke the driver.
- I only look for the drivers directly reachable via syscalls. By directly reachable I mean drivers designed to have some syscall interface with userspace. Yes, syscalls not aimed at a certain driver may still indirectly trigger code in that driver, but these indirect effects can be neglected.
- Maybe some background on my objective clarifies: I want to fuzz-test the found drivers using [Syzkaller](https://github.com/google/syzkaller). For this, I would create descriptions of the syscalls usable to fuzz each driver that Syzkaller parses.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure there is no way to do this programmatically.  Any attempt to do so would hit up against a couple of problems:

- The drivers that are called in a given case depend on the hardware.  For example, on my laptop, the `iwlwifi` driver will be reachable via network syscalls, but on a server that driver won't be used.
- Virtually any code loaded into the kernel is reachable from some syscall if the hardware is present.  Drivers interact with hardware, which in turn either interacts with users, external devices, or networks, and all of these operations are reachable by syscalls.  People don't write drivers that don't do anything.
- Even drivers that aren't directly reachable by a system call can affect execution.  For example, a driver for a true RNG would be able to affect execution by changing the behavior of the system PRNG, even if it weren't accessible by `/dev/hwrng`.

So for a generic kernel that can run on any hardware of a given architecture, it's going to be pretty hard to exclude any driver from consideration.  If your hope is to trace the execution of the code by some programmatic means without actually executing it, then you're going to need to solve the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: Thank you, I understand your points. I think I missed some important aspects that narrow down my problem, so I updated my question. Any way to tackle this under the updated conditions?